# How can I manage Queues in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, queue

Well, I'm trying to understand the Threading and Queues.

I saw many documents on the web, but surprisingly there is not even a single example of this topic in tensorflow 2.0.

What I want my queues to do is to,

1. Define an operation that generates examples.
2. Define a queue.
3. Define an enqueue_operation that enqueue examples in the queue made above using multiple threads.
4. Control this queue to dequeue batches.

What I have in mind is,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

batch_size = 2
example = tf.random.normal([1, 2]) # Generate an example, shape = [1, 2]
queue = tf.queue.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=10, min_after_dequeue=0, \
    dyptes=tf.float32, shapes=[1, 2])
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue(example)
# inputs = queue.dequeue(2) # Don't run this. This would stop your computer.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. I also learned that how to manage multiple threads using `tf.train.Coordinator()` but I don't know where to use this..

While asking this, I have a suspicion that many APIs in the `tf.data.Dataset` replace all of these and multiple threads can be replaced with the `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`.

Sorry for all the mess here. I can't arrange this properly even during asking. 
Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the preferred way is to use `tf.data.Dataset` API. You can follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch). I will also highlight the important code that will help you implement multithreading for your batch.

```
dataset = Dataset.range(1, 6)  # ==> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x + 1,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
    deterministic=False)
```

Also it is documented in that link the following:

> Performance can often be improved by setting num_parallel_calls so
> that map will use multiple threads to process elements. If
> deterministic order isn't required, it can also improve performance to
> set deterministic=False.

I think you should follow this API.

Also look at the `cache` and `prefetch` API, this optimizes the input pipeline.